# How to skip serializing an object if it null in Newtonsoft json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, null, json.net

I am using Json.net serializer for serializing objects.It is working perfectly.Now as per my requirement, I have used JsonDotNetCustomContractResolvers to exclude properties from an object.But for the below show object, I need to exclude all it properties.

```
Partial Public Class CreditCard
    <Key> _
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property CustomerID As Integer
    Public Property CardType As String
    Public Property Last4Digit As String
    Public Property ExpiryDate As String
    Public Property Token As String
    Public Property IsPrimary As Boolean
End Class
```

And when I do that I get the result as I wanted. Result Shown in below image.

[image] 
Here the properties are  excluded, but the null object is still serialized.Is there any way to skip the serialization of null objects in newtonsoft JSON.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  To clarify, you have a list of `CreditCard` objects, and want to skip serializing instances all of whose properties are `null`, correct?  The `CreditCard` itself is non-null, right?

Comment: Also, why are you using a custom contract resolver?  Why not set [`JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_NullValueHandling.htm)?  Or [`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm)?

Comment: Yes, I want to skip serializing the instances all of whose properties are null. -@dbc

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick test app to show you what you might want to try.
There is a great attribute for Json.Net, `JsonObject`, coupled with the setting `MemberSerialization.OptIn`.  This means that only properties with `JsonProperty` will be serialized.

```
public class JsonNet_35883686
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class CreditCard
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        var cc = new CreditCard {Id = 1, CustomerId = 123};
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cc);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        cc = null;
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cc);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

The output of run is (the reason `Id` is serialized is because I used `JsonProperty`

```
{"Id":1}
null
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NullValueHandling setting in Newtonsoft.Json to ignore objects or keys with null values.

```cs
string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

Ref: [NullValueHandling Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm)